# Share variables from different function

Tags: java, class, variables, scope

My first post here on stackoverflow! I also started learning Java.
I'm trying to build a program that prints a random letter, then it should write words that begin with that letter, and it has a class to verify.

The problem is when I generate a randomNum in order to get the randomLetter from the array, I can't share the randomNum variable with the class where it needs to be verified.

```
private void jButtonPlayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    int randomNum;

    randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*palavras.length);
    System.out.println(""+randomNum);


    jLabelRandom.setText(Introduce words that begins with : " + palavras[randomNum]);


}                                           

private void jButtonVerificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

    int certas = 0;

    String[] words = {jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText(), jTextField4.getText(),
                      jTextField4.getText()};         

    for (String w : words){

        if(w.startsWith(Integer.ToString(palavras[randomNum]))){ // This variable can't be shared here, but I need it here :)
            certas++;
        }
}

     jLabelCertas.setText(Integer.toString(certas));
     words = null;

}                                                

public String[] palavras = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"};
```

Comment: make `randomNum` a private instance variable of the class containing these functions.

Comment: Also, the title is misleading: you don't need to share variables between classes, but between functions...

Comment: ``palavras[randomNum]`` is already String! You don't need to cast.

Comment: @Iodo thanks for the help, also fixed that, I'm still really fresh on programming.

Comment: @Aero thanks! completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use `randomNum` as a local variable instead of as a data member. It seems you are mixing the concept of method with the concept of class as well, it would be very useful to read about methods and classes. As about the solution:

Remove this row from your `jButtonPlayActionPerformed` method:

```
int randomNum;
```

Instead of it, define `randomNum` as a member inside your class, but outside your methods, like this:

```
private int randomNum;

private void jButtonPlayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*palavras.length);
    System.out.println(""+randomNum);


    jLabelRandom.setText(Introduce words that begins with : " + palavras[randomNum]);


}                                           

private void jButtonVerificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

    int certas = 0;

    String[] words = {jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText(), jTextField4.getText(),
                      jTextField4.getText()};         

    for (String w : words){

        if(w.startsWith(Integer.ToString(palavras[randomNum]))){ // This variable can't be shared here, but I need it here :)
            certas++;
        }
}

     jLabelCertas.setText(Integer.toString(certas));
     words = null;

}                                                

public String[] palavras = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"};
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem! I'll check i'm still very fresh in programming.

Comment: I am happy to help you, gouzz. You should still read about the concepts to make sure your theoretical knowledge will help you. If my answer solved your problem, you can accept it, so it will help others as well, having similar problems.

Comment: Didn't know where I needed to accept it, but now it's done. I have another doubt here, maybe you know how to help me :)  if(w.endsWith(palavras[randomNum]))  -> I also wanna add the parameter "equalsIgnoreCase", how can I do it?

Comment: endsWith is case sensitive, but you convert your strings to be case insensitive. If you want to check whether myString ends with suffix in a case insensitive fashion, then you can convert both strings to lower, like this: myString.toLowerCase().endsWith(suffix.toLowerCase()). The values of the strings will not be changed, but whatever case was used, toLowerCase results in lower case. As a result, the comparison will be lowercase, which is exactly what you need.